# NodeJS Typescript cross Project references

Tags: node.js, typescript

Is it possible to achieve a project structure as shown below without the Typescript compiler recompiling shared portions of the code (in this case recompiling `src` for the tests), and getting cross-project refactoring support?

```
./
|- dist/
| |- ... /* output of tsc -p src */
|- src/
| |- ... /* bunches of files/folder etc. etc. */
| |- tsconfig.json // outDir is ../dist and declarations is true
|- test/
| |- ... /* lotsa tests */
| |- tsconfig.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is on [the typescript team's radar](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25600); and [it is officially a feature of Typescript 3.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/07/12/announcing-typescript-3-0-rc/).